# How can I cache image with "init(contentsOfFile:)"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In apple document

```
init?(named: String)
```

will load & cache image only from bundle but

```
init?(contentsOfFile: String)
```

will load but not cache image

---

1. If I save user image in document directory not in bundle. How can I load image & cache image ?
2. Can I save user image that capture form my app to custom bundle ?

Comment: You cannot save anything to bundle, it is read only.